# What is the difference between Byzantine fault tolerance and Practical Byzantine fault tolerance

Tags: system, distributed-computing, consensus

As the title says, what is the difference between Byzantine fault tolerance and Practical Byzantine fault tolerance. I tried finding answers online but was not successful.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve Byzantine fault tolerance in several possible ways, the most straight forward is all nodes talk to all nodes, telling what value they plan to accept. This required n * (n-1) messages in the network, with each on n nodes sending n-1 messages to other n-1 nodes.

Later down the line, someone proposed the pBFT algorithm that can achieve the Byzantine fault tolerance with less number of message exchange. Their paper says:

*"We implemented a Byzantine-fault-tolerant NFS service using our
algorithm and measured its performance. The results show that
our service is only 3% slower than a standard unreplicated NFS."*
https://pmg.csail.mit.edu/papers/osdi99.pdf

Later there were some attacks found on their algorithm, so the solution is not fully Byzantine fault tolerant.

So in short practical byzantine fault tolerant systems use pBFT protocol, which is mostly byzantine fault tolerant, with a couple of possible attacks.